# Jenkins: disable cross user from cancelling a build

Tags: groovy, jenkins

Assume user A has triggered a build in jenkins. My requirement is that, only user A should be able to cancel the build and none of the users should be able to cancel the build, is this possible and does it make sense? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box? No.
With Plugins? No.

You could always write some script that, at the start of job, figures out who started it, and then uses the API or modifies the job config file directly to change permissions on that job, forces Jenkins to reload from disk for the new configuration to take effect, and at the end of the job restores the original configuration...

But really... why? No, it doesn't make sense.

What makes sense is to make sure all users have unique logins. If a certain user is abusing his power, and constantly stopping other people's builds, you can see that user's name in the job log (you can trigger an email to yourself, if that user also deletes the job log history). When you see this becoming a pattern, first talk to the user, and then if he/she doesn't stop, remove his permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I am just playing with jenkins java api, and any idea how to remove permissions for a particular job...